# Yii error using migration tool

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to use the migration tool, but am getting the following error:

```
exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii-sandbox/framework/db/CDbConnection.php:382
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii-sandbox/framework/db/CDbConnection.php(330): CDbConnection->open()
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii-sandbox/framework/db/CDbConnection.php(308): CDbConnection->setActive(true)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii-sandbox/framework/base/CModule.php(387): CDbConnection->init()
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii-sandbox/framework/cli/commands/MigrateCommand.php(442): CModule->getComponent('db')
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii-sandbox/framework/cli/commands/MigrateCommand.php(451): MigrateCommand->getDbConnection()
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii-sandbox/framework/cli/commands/MigrateCommand.php(482): MigrateCommand->getMigrationHistory(-1)
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii-sandbox/framework/cli/commands/MigrateCommand.php(84): MigrateCommand->getNewMigrations()
#7 [internal function]: MigrateCommand->actionUp(Array)
#8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii-sandbox/framework/console/CConsoleCommand.php(172): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(MigrateCommand), Array)
#9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii-sandbox/framework/console/CConsoleCommandRunner.php(71): CConsoleCommand->run(Array)
#10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii-sandbox/framework/console/CConsoleApplication.php(92): CConsoleCommandRunner->run(Array)
#11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii-sandbox/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): CConsoleApplication->processRequest()
#12 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii-sandbox/framework/yiic.php(33): CApplication->run()
#13 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii-sandbox/projects/trackstar/protected/yiic.php(7): require_once('/Applications/M...')
#14 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii-sandbox/projects/trackstar/protected/yiic(4): require_once('/Applications/M...')
```

I have checked the DB settings in `console.php`, which are as follows:

```
'db'=>array(
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=yii_trackstar, unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'username' => 'yii',
    'password' => 'xxx',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
),
```

As you can see, I've tried setting the host to 127.0.0.1 and setting the unix socket as per other suggestions.

I'm using MAMP (as you can see). from the protected dir, I'm running the command: `./yiic migrate`

No matter what I change, I get the same error message.

**Update: **

I've just realized something. Changing the `host=localhost` to `host=127.0.0.1` actually gives me a different error of `connection refused`. If I set that back to `localhost` the error is as follows:

```
exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii-sandbox/framework/db/CDbConnection.php:382
```

Comment: Do you need to use the `unix_socket` in the connection?  My connection string typically works like this: `'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii_trackstar'`

Comment: tried it both with and without. I added the unix_socket at the suggestion that it's sometimes needed. same w/ changing localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Using Finder or Terminal, are you able to navigate to the folder `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql`? If not, update that path in your connection string to the actual location of that folder on your system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the yii framework forum, there is already similar question posted at [http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/16-db-connection-string](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/16-db-connection-string/page__p__70#entry70)

**NOTE**

Specifically, what solved it is this from that thread:

A note on PHP and Mac OSX:
A version of PHP4 comes bundled on Mac OSX and is typically what is executed when you try the php command from the command line.  You need to have the php command execute a version of PHP5.x or higher.  Usually, you have already installed a version of PHP5.x or higher, but need to tell the php command to execute the newer version rather than the older one.  There are certainly many ways to achieve this, but here is one:

At any terminal prompt, type in:

```
prompt>which php
```

this should tell you where the OS is looking for the php command tells me `/usr/bin/php`.
If I navigate to `/usr/bin` and issue an `ls *php*` I will see three files:

```
php
php-config
phpize
```

These are all for the bundled version PHP4.x
Rename these files to use a 4 in their names, to remember these are the executables for PHP4

```
mv php php4
mv php-config php-config4
mv phpize phpize4
```

Then, create sym links for each of these these to point to the PHP5.x or higher version you have installed.  In my case these are located in `/usr/local/apache/php/bin`.  So I would issue from the `/usr/bin` directory

```
ln -s [absolute path to your php5.x] php
```

and similarly for the other files.

Comment: Really helps, thanks. Who have console.php with correct DB connection data and also have PDO installed and get such error - this is your solution. Only one thing if you  use MAMP: your php5 will not in /usr/bin. In my case these files are located in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/PHP VERSION/bin/

Answer (score 2):

While running yyic I've got problems until I've changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 in the connection string.

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the port in the host string. So `localhost:8889` instead of just `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` — whichever you use.

This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the `unix_socket` with the correct keyword `Socket` and in the same way as the other vars in the string with `;` and no spaces:

```
'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii_trackstar;Socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
```

You can check more connection strings over here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

Comment: 'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=yii_trackstar;unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',

Answer (score 1):

Try setting host=127.0.0.1 on your db.php file

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution:

Just open the  ***mail-local.php***  page inside  **backend/common/config**  directory. 
 Then change **localhost**   to **127.0.0.1** . 
Now you run **php yii migrate** .
Hope, It will successfully create the tables in Databse

Answer (score 0):

change connection string to this

```
'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii_trackstar',
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and use this

```
echo "export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.x.x/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.profile
```

5.x.x is your version of PHP you use

This is because Yii framework use your default PHP come with OSX, not the PHP of MAMP.
To make sure, type "which php" to see if it's /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.x.x/bin/php then you are done.

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a mac problem where it uses an older version of php that is installed on the machine as opposed to the php5 that comes with MAMP.  So I had to force it to use PHP version 5 that comes with MAMP.

So I had to write this in the Terminal and it worked:

/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/php /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projectname/protected/yiic migrate

Answer (score 0):

Edit file config/db.php

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=namedb',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

MAMP PRO click Enable Allow access to MySql at Mysql Menu.

Comment: some explanation of why there's an error and why does this fix it would be probably welcome